# IBM Watson. MessageRequest.Builder() issue

Tags: android, watson-conversation

I am working on building an Android app which uses the Watson Conversation API. I am following the tutorials mentioned [here](https://javapapers.com/android/android-ai-chatbot-powered-by-ibm-watson/) and [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-chatbots-on-android-with-ibm-watson--cms-29387).
However, it seems that quite a few of the Api's functions are deprecated. For example, the `ConversationService` is now `Conversation`.

Similarly, I am having an issue running this piece of code:

```
 MessageRequest request = new MessageRequest.Builder()
                        .inputText(userStatement)
                        .build();
```

It says `Cannot resolve symbol Builder`. Since the `MessageRequest` Class no longer has the builder(I guess). Any way around this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it..

```
MessageOptions newMessage = new MessageOptions.Builder().workspaceId("")
                .input(new InputData.Builder(userStatement).build()).context(context).build();
        MessageResponse response = service.message(newMessage).execute();
```

I think you are using older version of sdk.
Update it https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/releases
 Message request is no longer available. Use MessageOptions.

Comment: Sorry i answered it about java.

Comment: MessageOptions is the way to do it though. Holds true for Android as well.